# Representation of C# Collections

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to know how C# collections are represented in memory? Are they represented as linked list or an array.In my project I have to make extensive use of list and performance is critical, so shall I create custom generic Linked List(with some additional features) or shall I use generic List class. Any help will be highly appericiated.

Comment: Take a look at dictionaries http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys

Comment: It depends, so could you please be more specific. `List<T>` uses an array. `LinkedList<T>` is a doubly linked list. What collection did you have in mind?

Comment: Yes , I see List<T> makes use of an array. I have List<T> in my mind. I have used LinkedList in C alot but never in C# . If List<T> or any other collection that implements ICollection makes use of array than LinkedList<T> is better if we have to make extensive use of insertion and deletion in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Reflection (or ILSpy, etc) to view internal realization of c# collections